# Session Management in distributable web-apps

Tags: web, applications, session, cluster

I am working on a huge web application in which I need to add transparent failover feature. I understand the necessary steps to make a web application distributable, the most difficult thing being: to ensure that the objects stored in the session are serializable. I want to know which type of variables exactly should I store in the session? e.g. just login info or other things too.

The web application is actually a gateway to numerous other smaller applications like generating business reports, setting calander etc. So will I have to make those other applications also serializable or just the logon application will suffice ?

I am new to web development so excuse me if the question is trivial.

Comment: Do you have some "router" program in front of the other services? There you could handle the state and distribute it. Based on the used technology you could share sessions at that level keeping the applications behind it stateless.

Comment: Not exactly a "router". When logged in, the application shows links to other applications which can be opened individually but you would have to provide login info each time. To prevent this, my application was made so you could login once and browse through other applications seamlessly.

Comment: Ok so they access the applications directly from web to specific server? You don't have an application in between like can be seen in figure 5. on this page: http://www.infoq.com/articles/microservices-intro ? In that case it will be difficult because you would have the same logic in every application. You might just add some kind of proxy service in between which handles login/session and then requests the specific server. Then you can scale your real applications without any state.

Comment: That link was an excellent resource. I think I know now how to proceed.  Thanks for your comments.